# Java. How can I remove all lines up to a point from a BuffereReader value to avoid parsing them?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

At the moment I've got the below which is scraping data from a website.

```
        try {
        in = ServiceUtils.connect(url);
    } catch (Exception e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is great, and I can then iterate through each line to find what I want.

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
    //Do a whole bunch of stuff
}
```

However, the while loop means that I'll loop through the entire content of the page, when I already know that I want to look at content only after reaching a unique string of text as per below:

```
<caption>Latest Entries</caption>
```

How can I skip parsing each individual line of code? Is it possible to remove everything above that string before parsing?

Comment: Either *you* will loop, or a method you call will do the looping for you. That's a mighty small difference in the end.

Comment: You mean you want java to "look" at the page and skip lines without processing them and then focus on the one that you want? That would be awesome but I don't think you can exclude line of text without looking into it...

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of loading the whole page as a string, removing everything before that string and then parsing the remainder

Comment: You have a bad analysis. You may want to make a FilterStream. It allows to skip some bytes but it wont do the magic of parsing the text without parsing it. This is basically nonsense. You do not say how reading the content in line is related with your XML markap. Generally, XML tags may start at one line and finish at the others. I do not understand what you want to demonstrate with the line reader!

Comment: Ok, I'm going to have a look at a filterStream and see if this is a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you know its position on the page (how many characters are in front of it) then there is no real way to do that. You can't jump to a position without knowing the position to jump to, and the only way to find that position is to scan the file looking for your String.

What you can do is make sure you scan the file one line at a time and only start any other processing once you have found the line that matches your search string.

Any library methods (i.e. indexOf, matches, etc) will just have to do the same loop through scanning inside the method that you are doing outside the method.

I'd just do two while loops, the first consumes strings until you find a match, the second then processes.

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null &&
        inputLine.indexOf("<caption>Latest Entries</caption>")!=-1){
    // Do nothing
} 
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // Now do stuff
}
```

Comment: Your code checks if the input line CONTAINS the SKIP_TO_STR. Is this intended? I assumed we shall check if it is EQUAL to the SKIP_TO_STR...

Comment: Ironically I just changed it to EQUAL - I think the requirements are vague enough that either could be correct.

Comment: OP says "reaching the unique string" so I would go for the *contains* semantics.

Comment: Yeah, I think I might change it back. Either way it's fragile though as it relies on the string all being on one line, not split etc.

Comment: True, but if it's machine-generated (probably), then it will be fairly stable.

Comment: Yep, machine generated it'll always be like that and on one line.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really skip natively using BufferedReader, you'd have to use a state-machine-based construct like this:

```
boolean alreadyEncounteredCaption = false;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
    if(inputLine.equals("<caption>Latest Entries</caption>")) {
         alreadyEncounteredCaption = true;
    }
    if(alreadyEncounteredCaption) {
        //Do a whole bunch of stuff
    }
}
```

You could even extend `BufferedReader` to get a custom `Reader` class that automatically skips everything until a specified line.

Comment: It would be more efficient and simpler with two while loops, see my answer.